# MVC JavaScript inside foreach block

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

The textbox should be filled up with values from the table when the dedicated button is pressed.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Users, new { @id = "Name" })
```

... there for I need a button in every line of the table.

```
@foreach (var user in Model.Users)
{
    <tr>

        <td> <input type="button" value="get" id="btnTakeOver" class="btn btn-primary" /> </td>

        <td>@user.Id</td>
        <td>@user.Name</td>
        <td>@user.Email</td>
    </tr>

}
```

But I have the problem that the JavaScript doesn't know the variables  `@user.Name`  and `@user.Email` from the foreach block.

The JavaScript block.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btnTakeOver").click(function () {
                $("#Name").val(@user.Name);  // val from inside the foreach loop
                $("#Email").val(@user.Email);
            });

        });
        
    </script>
}
```

Has anybody an idea how it works?

Comment: you could add the name and the email as data attributes on the button: `<input type="button" data-name=@user.name data-email=@user.email value="get" id="btnTakeOver" class="btn btn-primary" />` then in the click handler you can use eg: $(this).data("name") to get the name.

Comment: I also suggest to change the id of the button to be a class. since ID's need to be unique

Comment: Use jQuery .on and target your tr instead of the button itself. That way you'll get the entire row of values. Using an id attribute will be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the data into onclick event of the button:

```
<td> <input type="button" value="get" id="btnTakeOver" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction(@user.Name,@user.Email)" /> </td>
```

js:

```
 <script>
      function myFunction(Name,Email){
          $("#Name").val(Name);  // val from inside the foreach loop
          $("#Email").val(Email);
      }
        
    </script>
```